# Why is my Minecraft earth character turning away from the tappable I want to get?

Tags: minecraft-earth

I’ve been trying to get lots of tappables in Minecraft earth but the annoying thing and it’s reallly annoying is that when my range is very close to a tappable my character turns and walks away from it instead!

Answer (score 0):

Your ability to collect tappables is based on your cell phone's physical location. Minecraft Earth will determine your physical location to the best of it's ability but this is not always 100% accurate. It's not that your character is idly walking around (and away from your tappable) but rather that that your cell phone evaluated that you were a little further away from the tappable than you though you were.

There isn't a solution to this because this isn't a glitch or technical error. Try walking closer to the tappable that you wish to collect.